# Creating an accessible list of results in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents

In one of my classes we have a lot of results and I would like to keep track of them and classify them. Basically what I would like to have is a main body consisting of three sections (definitions, results, examples) and before that have some kind of "indices" or "tables of content" which group the elements of these three sections by concepts. For example I could have one of this indices be "Convergence results" and in there I would have a list of all of the titles  of convergence results (or abbreviations of those) with hyperlinks to their position in the text. This way whenever I had to prove some kind of convergence I could go to my list and quickly see which results could be useful. Any ideas on what would be the best way of going about it?

Comment: You are talking about indices. The real indices. Have a look at `imakeidx` or `makeidx`.

Comment: While LaTeX has build in support for sections and subsections, you don't have to follow this structure.  You can use `\addcontentsline` to link to anchor point `\@currentHref`.

Comment: You can't do it just like this? `\tableofcontents
\section{Definitions}
....
\section{Results}
\subsection{Convergence results}
\subsubsection{Riemann convergence}
\subsubsection{Cauchy convergence}
\subsubsection{Other convergence}...\subsection{Algebre results}
....
\section{Examples}`

Comment: @touhami The problem is that perhaps a result falls into more than one category, and I don't want to have repeated theorems.